# How to create a div toggle effect using jQuery?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, menu, contextmenu

I want the following requirement. But there is slight change on it.

http://acrisdesign.com/demo/toggle/

Please consider the above link for the example below.

There are two toggle effects on Hover and Click.

My requirement when someone click on the top of the div: it will expand and there should be a "close" button in the div some on mouse over to this image or click the div will closed. When someone mouse hover the link it will expand.

```
  First time click expand when mouse over the link collapse.
```

There are toggle links "click here". When someone click on the link it will create a space between each other, but my requirement to it display top of the three link "click here".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Accordion

[Example one](http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/)

[Example 2](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/)

[Example 3](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

Something that I have found very useful is the .toggleClass() function in jQueryUI

http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/